# Packaging composite component in JSF2 with Netbeans 7.0.1, Maven

Tags: netbeans, maven, jsf-2, jar, composite-component

I've read a lot of things on the Internet about packaging JSF2 composite component in a JAR file.

Does somebody know where I can find what MUST be the structure of JAR (specs, official doc, etc, ). Is there a way to do it with Netbeans IDE, or does an archetype exist for Maven ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the JSF [`composite` tag library documentation summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/composite/tld-summary.html) (emphasis mine):

> #### Creating a Composite Component
>
> The default implementation must support authoring. A composite component is declared by creating a Facelets2 file inside of a resource library. (**See section JSF.2.6 of the specification prose document for more information about resource libraries.**) A composite component must reside within a resource library. It is not possible to create a composite component without putting it inside of a resource library.

From section 2.6 of [the JSF specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html):

> #### 2.6.1.2 Packaging Resources into the Classpath
>
> For the default implementation, resources packaged in the classpath must reside under the
>   JAR entry name:
>
> ```
> META-INF/resources/<resourceIdentifier>
> ```
>
> Resources packaged into the classpath must be accessed using the `getResource*()` methods of the `ClassLoader` obtained by calling the `getContextClassLoader()` method of the current `Thread`.

To the point, all composite components must go into `/META-INF/resources` folder of the JAR. It's to be treated the same way as `/WEB-INF/resources` in the regular WAR (so you still need an extra subfolder to represent the composite compnent's main namespace).

For the case that, if the JAR also contains classes with JSF annotations like `@ManagedBean` and such, then the JAR must also have a JSF 2.0 compatible `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` file in order to trigger the JSF annotation scanner to crawl the entire JAR for classes implementing any of the JSF annotations.

As to the Netbeans/Maven part, sorry I have no idea as I don't use them.

Comment: Hi BalusC, thanks a lot for your answer. I saw a lot of your posts and your website too. Really interesting. I will look with attention your links and try to make it work.